# Does the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange have a search feature to look for previous questions on a subject

Tags: discussion

Just registered and tried to find a search feature so I would not ask a duplicate question but did not find such a feature. I went to the help feature but it only searched in help and the create question feature did list some possible questions but I am asking if there is a full featured search for already created questions on particular subject matter.

Comment: Last I knew, as you start to ask a question, SE will suggest similar questions as potential duplicates. Additionally, if you have a specific question (and can't find an answer after your own searches, and none of the suggested questions help), go ahead and ask! Feel free to preemptively rule out potential duplicate Q/A's by explaining how you tried them or how they don't apply. A community member might find a duplicate that helps, but that's OK -- duplicates are sign posts (with different wording) with the same answer -- all guiding future searchers to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the screen, there’s a big text field which says “Search on Unix & Linux…”: type your search query there, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of this question, showing the search field]

Comment: But it's so useless, that you might as well use duckduckgo or your favourite web search engine and enter `site:unix.stackexchange.com your-search-terms-there`.